# Trying to embed plots that open in Quartz in R Markdown

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown, quartz-graphics

I was trying to make an R markdown report in which some of my R-code has a plot function that opens a Quartz screen to plot some graphs when I run the code in normal R.
However when I wanted to use the plot code in an R markdown script, the plots do not show up in my pdf output.

This is my code:

````
```{r TmatrixPlot, dev="quartz_pdf"}
cBt <- as.tmatrix(coryphanthaB, names.st = c("seed","juvenile","adult"))
cBt
plot(cBt)
```
````

And these are my general setting at the top of the page:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(Rramas)
library(grDevices)
library(devtools)
```
````

I am not that familiar with R markdown, so I quickly ran out of options to try and include the plot. Can anybody help me with this?

Thank you!